# Dictionary doesn't recognize key type

Tags: ios, xcode, dictionary, swift

With the beta 3 of Xcode the following piece of code doesn't work anymore:

```
func keyboardWasShown (notification: NSNotification)
{        
        var info = notification.userInfo
        keyboardSize = info.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey).CGRectValue().size        
}
```

at the instruction:

```
keyboardSize = info.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey).CGRectValue().size
```

XCode return the error [NSObject : AnyObject] does not have a member named objectForKey.

So i changed the code like this:

```
func keyboardWasShown (notification: NSNotification)
{

        var info = notification.userInfo
        keyboardSize = info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey].CGRectValue().size

}
```

but XCode returns the error "String is not a subtype f DictionaryIndex"

Comment: It seems that it doesn't know that userInfo is an NSDictionary.  Have you tried var info = `notification.userInfo as NSDictionary` ? with your first code

Comment: No, i've tryed it right now and it works perfectly! Thank you! But why it doesn't recognize userInfo like NSDictionary?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As of Xcode 6 Beta 3, `NSDictionary*` is now imported from Objective-C APIs as `[NSObject : AnyObject]` (this change is documented in the release notes).

So you can access the dictionary value with `info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]`.
This gives an `AnyObject` which you have to cast to `NSValue`, so that `CGRectValue()` can be applied:

```
var info = notification.userInfo
let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as NSValue).CGRectValue().size
```

The error message

> 'String' is not a subtype of 'DictionaryIndex'

is quite misleading, the problem with your second attempt is only the missing cast.

**Update for Xcode 6.3:** `notification.userInfo` is an *optional* dictionary now and must be unwrapped, e.g. with optional binding.
Also the forced cast operator `as` has been renamed to `as!`:

```
if let info = notification.userInfo {
    let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue().size
} else {
    // no user info
}
```

We can forcefully unwrap the dictionary value because it is *documented*
to be a `NSValue` of a `CGRect`.