# [NSObject : AnyObject]?' does not have a member named 'subscript' error in Xcode 6 beta 6

Tags: ios, dictionary, swift, xcode6-beta6

I used the below couple of code lines to get the frame of the keyboard when its shown on the screen. I've registered to `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` notification.

```
func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification) {
    var info = notification.userInfo
    var keyboardFrame: CGRect = info.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey).CGRectValue()
}
```

This used to work in beta 5. I downloaded the latest Xcode 6 version which is beta 6 and this error occurred at the second line.

**'[NSObject : AnyObject]?' does not have a member named 'objectForKey'**

After some Googling, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24628441/1077789) solution. And I changed it like so,

```
var keyboardFrame: CGRect = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as NSValue).CGRectValue()
```

But it seems that's also outdated now. Because I get this error now.

**'[NSObject : AnyObject]?' does not have a member named 'subscript'**

I can't figure out this error or how to resolve it.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

As mentioned in the Xcode 6 beta 6 release notes, a large number of Foundation APIs have been audited for optional conformance.
These changes replace `T!` with either `T?` or `T` depending on whether the value can be null (or not) respectively.

`notification.userInfo` is now an *optional* dictionary:

```
class NSNotification : NSObject, NSCopying, NSCoding {
    // ...
    var userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]? { get }
    // ...
}
```

so you have to unwrap it. If you *know* that `userInfo` is not `nil` then
you can simply use a "forced unwrapping":

```
var info = notification.userInfo!
```

but note that this will crash at runtime if `userInfo` is `nil`.

Otherwise better use an optional assignment:

```
if let info = notification.userInfo {
    var keyboardFrame: CGRect = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
} else {
    // no userInfo dictionary present
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Martin. It worked. I went with the unwarpping. Is there any downsides to it?

Comment: @Isuru: See updated answer. If you *know* that `userInfo` is not `nil` then you can just unwrap. Otherwise use the optional assignment.

Comment: I get an error with Swift 1.2: Cannot subscript a value of type 'AnyObject' with an index of type String

Comment: @VanDuTran: That is strange. I have double-checked the code with Swift 1.2 and with Swift 2 and it compiles without problems for me.