# [NSObject : AnyObject]?' does not have a member named 'subscript' in Xcode 6 Beta 6

Tags: ios, swift

I am building an app in Xcode 6 Beta 6 in Swift and I keep getting this error:

```
[NSObject : AnyObject]?' does not have a member named 'subscript'
```

I have no idea how to fix this. I have tried looking at this [[NSObject : AnyObject]?' does not have a member named 'subscript' error in Xcode 6 beta 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25381338/nsobject-anyobject-does-not-have-a-member-named-subscript-error-in-xcode) but I still don't understand how that solves the problem. If someone could explain that to me, that would be very nice. If you want to see my code, here it is:

```
import UIKit

class TimelineTableViewController: UITableViewController {

 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    if ((PFUser.currentUser()) != nil) {

        //Create an UIAlertController if there isn't an user
        var loginAlert:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Sign Up/ Log In", message: "Please sign up or log in", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        //Add a textView in the Log In Alert for the username
        loginAlert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({
            textfield in
            textfield.placeholder = "Your Username"
        })

        //Add a textView in the Log In Alert for the password
        loginAlert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({
            textfield in
            textfield.placeholder = "Your Password"
            textfield.secureTextEntry = true
        })

        //Place the user-input into an array and set the username and password accordingly for Log In
        loginAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Login", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
            alertAction in
            let textFields:NSArray = loginAlert.textFields as NSArray
            let usernameTextfield:UITextField = textFields.objectAtIndex(0) as UITextField
            let passwordTextfield:UITextField = textFields.objectAtIndex(1) as UITextField

            PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(usernameTextfield.text, password: passwordTextfield.text){
                (user:PFUser!, error:NSError!)->Void in
                if ((user) != nil){
                    println("Login successfull")
                }else{
                    println("Login failed")
                }


            }

        }))

        //Place the user-input into an array and set the username and password accordingly for Sign Up
        loginAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Sign Up", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
            alertAction in
            let textFields:NSArray = loginAlert.textFields as NSArray
            let usernameTextfield:UITextField = textFields.objectAtIndex(0) as UITextField
            let passwordTextfield:UITextField = textFields.objectAtIndex(1) as UITextField

            var sweeter:PFUser = PFUser()
            sweeter.username = usernameTextfield.text
            sweeter.password = passwordTextfield.text

            sweeter.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock{
                (success:Bool!, error:NSError!)->Void in
                if !(error != nil){
                    println("Sign Up successfull")
                }else{
                    let errorString = error.userInfo["error"] as NSString
                    println(errorString)
                }


            }

        }))
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Here is where the error is occuring:

[image]

Please tell me why this is occurring. Thanks!

Comment: which line? you can do `foo![bar]` to workaround the problem

Comment: Sorry, completely forgot to add where the error was. Added it now and what do you mean by 'foo![bar]' @BryanChen

Comment: `error.userInfo!["error"] as NSString`

Comment: OMG, Thank you so much. Worked like a charm. You might want to add it as an answer so that others may see it as well. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The error message is saying you can't do `[]` on `Optional` value. What you need to do is unwrap it.

```
error.userInfo!["error"] as NSString
```

or if you want to be safe

```
if let errorString = error.userInfo?["error"] as NSString {
     println(errorString)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've been scratching my head for 2 DAYS!

Comment: Thanks !!! But in the document and in the tutorial video it is written like that and they don't get any  error. How? Why they don't get that error?