# Swift custom Keyboard Error

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I keep getting an **Cannot convert expression's type '[NSObject : AnyObject]?' to 'NSDictionary'** error and I don't know what to do. I tried everything, looked everywhere. Can you please help? I am creating a custom keyboard in SWIFT and I am totally new at this so i could definitely use the help.

```
    // Called when `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` is sent.

func keyboardWillShow(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    let info = aNotification.userInfo as NSDictionary **<<<<<<<<<ERROR HERE>>>>>>>**
    let sizeBegin = info.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey).CGRectValue().size
    let sizeEnd = info.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey).CGRectValue().size

    let duration = info.objectForKey(UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey).doubleValue
    let curve = info.objectForKey(UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey).integerValue


    var animationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurve
    if let value = UIViewAnimationCurve.fromRaw(curve) {
        animationCurve = value
    } else {
        animationCurve = UIViewAnimationCurve.EaseInOut
    }

    let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 44, left: 0, bottom: sizeEnd.height, right: 0)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
        self.textView.contentInset = insets
        self.textView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets
    }, completion: nil)
}

// Called when `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` is sent.
func keyboardWillHide(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    let info = aNotification.userInfo as NSDictionary **<<<<<<<<<<ERROR HERE>>>>>>**
    let sizeBegin = info.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey).CGRectValue().size
    let sizeEnd = info.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey).CGRectValue().size

    let duration = info.objectForKey(UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey).doubleValue
    let curve = info.objectForKey(UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey).integerValue


    var animationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurve
    if let value = UIViewAnimationCurve.fromRaw(curve) {
        animationCurve = value
    } else {
        animationCurve = UIViewAnimationCurve.EaseInOut
    }

    let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 44, left: 0, bottom: sizeEnd.height, right: 0)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
        self.textView.contentInset = insets
        self.textView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25381338/nsobject-anyobject-does-not-have-a-member-named-subscript-error-in-xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary is of type `[NSObject:AnyObject]?` which is an Optional type that must be unwrapped to be used.  Since it is an Optional, it could be `nil`.  One safe way of dealing with this is to use the *nil coalescing operator* `??` to unwrap it:

```
let info = (aNotification.userInfo ?? [:]) as NSDictionary
```

That will either unwrap your dictionary if it is not `nil` or give you a new empty dictionary if it is `nil`.

Comment: sorry, now I'm getting a ]'AnyObject?' does not have a member named ...]

Comment: Take a look at @MartinR's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25381771/1630618