# Get object from [NSString: AnyObject] as UIViewAnimationCurve?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, dictionary

I have the following code:

```
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo

    let animationCurve = userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as UIViewAnimationCurve
    let animationDuration = userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as NSTimeInterval
    let keyboardFrame = userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as CGRect
```

`userInfo` is a `[NSObject: AnyObject]?` dictionary and the `UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey` keys are all `NSString!`s. Now I want to get some elements from this dictionary. But it seems not all items I want to use inherit from `AnyObject`. `UIViewAnimationCurve` is an `enum` and `CGRect` is a `struct`.

I am translating this code from Objective-C, where the following syntax is used:

```
[[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationCurve];
```

Now I want to know how I can get these elements from the dictionary without using (unsafe) pointers.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25381771/1187415 for the UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey. Similar code should work for UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey.

Comment: That works for the CGRect, but not for the `UIViewAnimationCurve`, as this is an enum. I guess I'll cast it to an `Int` and then use its raw value to initialize it, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` is a `NSValue` representing
a `CGRect`:

```
if let tmp = userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
    let keyboardFrame = tmp.CGRectValue()
}
```

The value of `UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey` is a `NSNumber`
representing the integer value of the enumeration:

```
if let tmp = userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber {
    let animationCurve = UIViewAnimationCurve(rawValue: tmp.integerValue)!
}
```

This can be combined into single expressions, using the nil-coalescing
operator `??` to provide default values:

```
let keyboardFrame = (userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() ?? CGRectZero
let animationCurve = UIViewAnimationCurve(rawValue:
        (userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber)?.integerValue ?? 0
    ) ?? .Linear
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. This works. Where can I find the documentation on what keys are in this dictionary?

Comment: @vrwim: All the keys are described in the UIWindow documentation.