# How do I setup a sign in page using parse and swift in Xcode (error with 'signInBackgroundWithBlock')?

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to setup a sign in page using parse and swift in Xcode but I keep getting an error with 'signInBackgroundWithBlock' how do I make this work?
I keep receiving the message

> Cannot invoke 'signUpInBackgroundWithBlock' with an argument list of
>   type `((Bool!, NSError!) -> Void)`

so far this is what I have and I just have an error with that part.

```
import UIKit
import Parse


class EmailLogin: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var statusLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var createAccountButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        emailTextField.delegate = self;
        passwordTextField.delegate = self;

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func createAccountButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        if verifyEmailDomain(self.emailTextField.text)
        {
            createAccount(self.emailTextField.text, password: self.passwordTextField.text)
        }
        else
        {
            //self.statusLabel.text = "Email domain is not valid.";

            let alert = UIAlertView()
            alert.title = "Invalid Email Domain"
            alert.message = "Make sure you entered in your address correctly. If you did, ask your system about using PageMD! Thanks."
            alert.addButtonWithTitle("Close")
            alert.show()
        }


    }

    func verifyEmailDomain(email: String) -> Bool
    {
        var isVerifiedDomain = false
        let userDomain: String = (email.componentsSeparatedByString("@")).last!

        //NSLog(userDomain)

        let validDomainsFileLocation = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("ValidDomains", ofType: "txt")
        var validDomainsFileContent = NSString(contentsOfFile: validDomainsFileLocation!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)

        //NSLog(validDomainsFileContent!)

        let validDomains = validDomainsFileContent!.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
        for domain in validDomains
        {
            NSLog(domain as! NSString as String)

            if userDomain == (domain as! NSString)
            {
                isVerifiedDomain = true
                break
            }
        }

        return isVerifiedDomain
    }

    func createAccount(email: String, password: String)
    {
        var newUser = PFUser()

        newUser.username = email // We want the user to login only with their email.
        newUser.email = email
        newUser.password = password

//this where i get my error//

        newUser.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { (succeeded: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil
            {
                // Account created successfully!
                if succeeded == true
                {
                    self.statusLabel.text = "Account created!"
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if let errorField = error.userInfo
                {
                    self.statusLabel.text = (errorField["error"] as NSString)
                }
                else
                {
                    // No userInfo dictionary present
                    // Help from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25381338/nsobject-anyobject-does-not-have-a-member-named-subscript-error-in-xcode
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool
    {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true;
    }
}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

Comment: the `succeeded: Bool` parameter of the block is probably not optional, try removing the `!`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3) you need to call the function by:

```
newUser.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({(succeeded:Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in

})
```

And if you are using swift 1.1 (Xcode 6.1, 6.2) you need to call the function by:

```
newUser.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({(succeded:Bool, error:NSError!) -> Void in

})
```

This is different because of the swift update 1.2 which has changes with using optionals.

Another way is to write it like this:
(Works in old and new swift)

```
newuser.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { (succeded, error) -> Void in

}
```

Comment: thank you so much! the first line worked for me i appreciate the help!