# I am setting up my sign up and login page using parse on xcode with swift but i keep getting a fatal error. Can somebody see what im doing wrong?

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform, fatal-error

this is what i have so far:

```
import Foundation
import Parse
import UIKit
import Bolts

class SignUpViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var statusLabel: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!


    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!


    @IBOutlet weak var createAccountButton: UIButton!


    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        emailTextField.delegate = self;
        passwordTextField.delegate = self;
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func createAccountButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        if verifyEmailDomain(self.emailTextField.text)
        {
            createAccount(self.emailTextField.text, password: self.passwordTextField.text)
        }
        else
        {
            //self.statusLabel.text = "Email domain is not valid.";

            let alert = UIAlertView()
            alert.title = "Invalid Email Domain"
            alert.message = "Make sure you entered in your address correctly. If you did, ask your system about using PageMD! Thanks."
            alert.addButtonWithTitle("Close")
            alert.show()
        }


    }

    func verifyEmailDomain(email: String) -> Bool
    {
        var isVerifiedDomain = false
        let userDomain: String = (email.componentsSeparatedByString("@")).last!

        //NSLog(userDomain)

        let validDomainsFileLocation = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("ValidDomains", ofType: "txt")
        var validDomainsFileContent = NSString(contentsOfFile: validDomainsFileLocation!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)

       // NSLog(validDomainsFileContent! as String)

        let validDomains = validDomainsFileContent!.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
        for domain in validDomains
        {
            NSLog(domain as! NSString as String)

            if userDomain == (domain as? NSString)
            {
                isVerifiedDomain = true
                break
            }
        }

        return isVerifiedDomain
    }

    func createAccount(email: String, password: String)
    {
        var newUser = PFUser()

        newUser.username = email // We want the user to login only with their email.
        newUser.email = email
        newUser.password = password

        newUser.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil
            {
                // Account created successfully!
                if succeeded == true
                {
                    self.statusLabel.text = "Account created!"
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if let errorField = error!.userInfo
                {
                    self.statusLabel.text = (errorField["error"] as! NSString) as String
                }
                else
                {
                    // No userInfo dictionary present
                    // Help from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25381338/nsobject-anyobject-does-not-have-a-member-named-subscript-error-in-xcode
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool
    {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true;
    }
}
```

when i run it i receive this in my terminal for xcode:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

and highlighted in green is:

```
var validDomainsFileContent = NSString(contentsOfFile: validDomainsFileLocation!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
```

what can i do to avoid this error?
I'm trying to create a login that uses the emailVerified feature from parse but I keep receiving this error and cant save the email to the core or send the verification email to the user. What can i do to make this code work and stop the error from coming up?

Comment: Have you verified that your `validDomainsFileLocation` is not nil? Is "ValidDomains.txt" a file included in your bundle app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, the file at `validDominsfileContent` wasn't found. You need to make sure that the file is included in your Bundle.

To do that, open the Bundle-Resources:

> Project > App target > Build Phases > Copy bundle resources

There you save your file. Now it should be found by Swift.